# Limiting the number of arguments in a variadic function

Tags: c++, variadic

So I've been working on a function class, and by default, I can do this, and it works:

```
int main(){
    function f("x^2+1");
    cout<<f(3)<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

"assume proper includes and namespaces"

Anyways, I would like to be able to pass in multiple variables, and even state what those variables are, like;

```
function f("x^2+y^2",x,y); // it doesn't really matter if it's x, 'x', or "x"
cout<<f(3,4)<<endl; // input 3 as x, and 4 as y
```

I'm fairly certain I could figure something out for the constructor using variadic functions, and even solve properly, but would there be a way to force the operator() arguments to take in exactly 2 values?

I was just looking at variadic functions because they are really the first things I've seen in c++ that can take in multiple arguments, so if it is better to do this some other way, I'm all for it.

Comment: My recommendation is to start with a simpler use case for variadic templates to get down how they're normally used.  In order to solve this particular problem you'll need to work out partial application of arguments to the function representation (because variadic templates are recursive), which isn't very trivial.

Comment: I would caution against using normal C variadic functions for this, because they're not strictly safe.  (See printf vulnerabilities.)

Answer (score 4):

You can limit the number of variadic arguments by using a `static_assert`.

```
template <typename ... Args>
void operator()(Args&&... args)
{
 static_assert(sizeof...(Args) <= 2, "Can deal with at most 2 arguments!");
}
```

Or you could use an `enable_if`

```
template <typename ... Args>
auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) <= 2>
{
}
```

Comment: I would most likely use the first one, but how exactly does it work? Would this return a compiling error if I passed in three arguments? Otherwise, I can just compare the sizeof...(Args) to the size passed into the constructor. Also, is there a specific reason that you are using a variadic template? How about having (Args args&&...)? All of the variables I will be inputting will be treated as doubles anyways, so is there a point for the template?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
using double_t=double;
template<class...Ts>
using nfun=std::function<double(double_t<Ts>...)>;

template<class...C>
nfun<C...> func(const char*,C...c);
```

that will return a n-ary `std::function` equal to the number of 'variable' arguments to `func`.

So `func("x^2+y",'x','y','z')` will return `std::function<double(double,double,double)>` as an example.

Comment: you probably meant `decltype(void(std::declval<Ts>()),0.)...`

Comment: @piotrs. or just kill the decltype entirely.